# Dropbox Public Folder and HTML previews

Tags: dropbox

So I was trying to send a colleague the files for a simple HTML page and decided to just throw it into my Dropbox Public Folder in case he loses it. When I went for the Public Link I noticed that the index page did not download but showed up in the browser.

It did show anything though as the links were wrong obviously so I decided to see how far I can push and try to link the files back through the public links. This is the [result](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5330881/test.html). Is it wrong to use the public folder in this way? And if not, how far can I go with it in terms of HTML pages?

Comment: Actually, today I tried to share a HTML page with a public link. But I'm disapointed because it shows a download link instead of a preview ! Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is fine if you are only testing something for a few friends.  However, there is an issue with using too much bandwidth if you try to host something through your public folder that becomes too popular.  As per https://www.dropbox.com/help/45:

> There are currently no hard limits on
>   public bandwidth usage. We do,
>   however, have an automated system for
>   detecting and flagging unusual amounts
>   of bandwidth usage. We will send an
>   email notification whenever an account
>   is flagged. Once flagged, public links
>   will be temporarily disabled and users
>   who use the links will see an error
>   page instead of your file.