# Is it possible to use Dropbox for showing off content on a website?

Tags: dropbox

I am planning a simple video sharing module on a project where a user can upload a video on our module using his Dropbox and is able to show it through our module. I believe I can do using their API and in fact I guess some mobile apps do use Dropbox for sharing/accessing user files. So, is it possible?

Comment: Indirectly related: [Dropbox Public Folder and HTML previews](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/337/dropbox-public-folder-and-html-previews)

Comment: FYI: they will restrict access to public/shared links that generate too much traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

Setting folder access to publicly shared allows anyone to embed, access and view the content within, but keep in mind, Dropbox *will* throttle access if you link a 50MB video and you use an insane amount of bandwidth to stream it.
The [chunked_upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#chunked-upload) function may be of interest to you.